# Minecraft Java Issue?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I just bought Minecraft for my PC and installed Java 8 and it was working fine until I installed the Java Development Kit 8 as well for some Android development. Now when I launch the game I cannot select (Highlight) any world I created or select (Highlight) any world I'm invited to. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java 8 (dun dun dun!)

Java 8 isn't really ready yet, so to speak. Uninstall it and the JDK, and get Java 7.

Comment: fun fact: android + java8 wont work. Android needs java 7 or on older devices java 6 ;)